# Unsigned types and jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I wanted to try out Jetpack Compose but an issue prevent me from doing so in my project.

I opened my project using Android Studio Artic Fox 2020.3.1 Beta 3 and downgraded my version of kotlin for this project from 1.5.10 to 1.4.32 as it is required by Jetpack Compose.

top level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

app level build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

After doing that, I get multiple errors due to unsigned types, for example:

```
Unresolved reference: toUShort
```

Which come from this code

```kotlin
val myShort: Short = 2
val myUShort: UShort = myShort.toUShort()
```

The IDE does not show me those errors, it only happen when I try to build my application. If I Ctrl + Click on the toUShort method it show me the documentation of kotlin-stdlib-common:1.5.0, where I can see the method is annotated with "@SinceKotlin("1.5")".

This is weird, as I'm using unsigned types since Kotlin 1.4.10. It was previously in beta and I had to add some kind of "@Experimental" annotation but it always worked until now.

How can I solve this? I need to try out Jetpack Compose but I can't get ride of unsigned type without scrapping a big part of my code base.

Comment: My understanding is that tomorrow's `beta08` will add Kotlin 1.5.0 support.

Comment: 1.0.0-beta08 is now public and it works with kotlin 1.5.10